# Including an executable inside a cpp file

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I have been working on a program and through testing I have found that I may need to include a secondary executable to run with the program, this is not an included program but one I've written, I have searched on Google as well as on here, however, there is no documentation. I am using Eclipse as my IDE so I cannot use any Visual Studios tools.
This is a windows based application.

Comment: This is more of an issue with an *installer* or a platform specific executable format.

Comment: C++ has no idea what an executable is. The way you do this depends on your operating system conventions.

Comment: The question can not be answered in its current form. You need to be much more specific about what you want to do and also what platform you are using.

Comment: If you wrote the executable, you presumably have access to its code. In that case why not just use its code?

Comment: I cannot use the code in the executable because it uses a while loop to operate and it must run parallel to the code I am trying to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot use the code in the executable because it uses a while loop
>   to operate and it must run parallel to the code I am trying to run

An unexpected response from you ... what prevents you from running the 'secondary executable' as a thread in the existing executable?

---

Consider:  If the 'secondary executable' code is 'packaged' as a 'main()', (and you have the code) you might simply rename the 'main' to something else, perhaps 'foo()', perhaps 'main2(int, char**)', or even 'secondary_executable(int, char**)' ...

```
// rename secondary executable 'main' to 
void foo(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    // example for test purposes ... input echo
    std::cout<< "\n  " << argc;
    for (int i = 1; i<argc; ++i) std::cout << "  " << argv[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // for test purposes - do something for 50 ms
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "foo executing << "  " << i << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere in your 'main', you do something like (not tested, not compiled):

```
std::thread t2(foo, argc, argv); // pass both by value
```

This statement starts the thread (t2) which runs in parallel.

If you must synchronize its termination, add an appropriate join.

---

Does this secondary require more argv's than the original?

Because argv is simply a list of strings, you can add the new argv's to your parameter list (and descriptions to your documentation, and an update to the 'usage' user prompt, etc.)

---

If your secondary executable is not C++ (nor C), I suppose the fall back approach to consider is to fork or popen() the secondary executable from within your C++ code.  On *nix, the secondary executable will run as a parallel process, with the pipe interface.

Comment: A possible approach suggest by Garrett Gutierrez comment.

Comment: Great solution! However, I'm running into an issue where MinGW does not allow me to compile with thread, so if you have a workaround or an alternative class, please let me know

Comment: Update: I found working headers on Github and it did compile! Thanks for your help

Comment: Congrats.  One alternative to C++ threads might be 'posix threads'.

Comment: @stranger080   FYI -- A C++ app (on Ubuntu 17.10) that uses "std::thread" will _fail_ to link without the build command having a "-lpthread", which also is needed for 'posix threads'. C++ thread code is much more convenient than posix, but both are functional.

Comment: Good to know, however I am building on Windows 10 and it's windows specific so that wont be a problem

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an issue with an *installer* or a platform specific executable format.

You should use an OS API to execute the secondary program.

I recommend packaging your secondary program along with your executable and other libraries.  This can be performed by using an installer utility (which is platform specific).

Placing data in an executable is outside the scope of the standard C++ language.